# C++ - Safety of reinterpret_cast for pointer-to-primitives

Tags: c++, casting, type-safety, reinterpret-cast

I've come across a piece of code in a project I'm evaluating, and wanted to know if the following cast is safe:

```
void func(unsigned long* input);
...
int data = 42;
func(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&data));  
// Casting to remove compiler warnings about data type not matching type expected
```

I know that with just simple C-style casting (ie: `(unsigned long*)&data`) that this is asking for trouble. Does `reinterpret_cast` automagically make this type of casting operating safe?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not &static_cast<int>(data)?

Comment: @KABoissonneault Is that a guaranteed safe operation? It looks sensible to me. Thanks!

Comment: @KABoissonneault You can't take an address of a prvalue. That won't compile.

Comment: @Barry Meh, then assign static_cast<unsigned long> (that's what I meant in my first comment) to a local variable first, then take its address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not safe: the program behaviour is undefined.

This is because the pointer types are unrelated.

Comment: Would the `&static_cast<int>(data)` suggested in the comments be safe?

Comment: No. To be safe you need to convert your int to an unsigned long: but check if it is of suitable size. Then call your function, and convert back, checking sizes once again. numeric_limits is helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

Any C-style cast gets interpreted as a particular C++-style cast. The C-style cast `(unsigned long*)&data` really means `reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&data)`. It's not possible for one of these to be safe when the other is unsafe.

And you're right, this is unsafe. Strictly speaking, it's generally not the cast itself that's the problem, although it could be. The cast itself is only a problem if `data` is not properly aligned for `unsigned long`. It's actually a subsequent access through the wrong type that's the problem. You don't show that access in your question, but unless `func` just casts `input` back to `int *`, or to `char *`, that's going to be a problem. And if `func` does cast it back like that, then it should just be declared to take the proper type.

Comment: Would the `&static_cast<int>(data)` suggested in the comments be safe?

Comment: @Dogbert It won't even compile, so it can't misbehave at run-time either. In that sense, it's safe. :)